# io.Copy cause out of memory in golang

Tags: go

I use io.Copy() to copy a file, about 700Mb, but it cause out of memory

```
bodyBuf := &bytes.Buffer{}
bodyWriter := multipart.NewWriter(bodyBuf)

//key step
fileWriter, err := bodyWriter.CreateFormFile(paramName, fileName)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

file, err := os.Open(fileName) //the file size is about 700Mb
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer file.Close()

//iocopy
copyLen, err := io.Copy(fileWriter, file) // this cause out of memory
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("io.copy(): ", err)

    return nil, err
}
```

The error message as follow:

```
runtime: memory allocated by OS (0x752cf000) not in usable range [0x18700000,0x98700000)
runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 1080229888-byte block (1081212928 in use)
fatal error: out of memory
```

I allocate enough memory for buf, it cause out of memory in bodyWriter.CreateFormFile()

```
buf := make([]byte, 766509056)
bodyBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(buf)
bodyWriter := multipart.NewWriter(bodyBuf)

fileWriter, err := bodyWriter.CreateFormFile(paramName, fileName) // out of memory
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Comment: Please don't post links to images capturing *text in a terminal* when you can just copy and paste the text itself (as you did) -- even when you get enough reputation ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you are 'copying', to `bodyBuf`, which is an in-memory buffer, forcing Go to try an allocate a block of memory as big as the entire file.

Based on your use of `multipart` it looks like you are trying to stream the file over http? In that case, don't pass a `bytes.Buffer` to `multipart.NewWriter`, directly pass your http connection instead.

Comment: Thanks. And did you mean directly writing the file to the post request body?

Comment: Depends if you're sending it as a request or a response, but basically.

Comment: I still can not get it work well.  I set the bodybuf enough memory, but the same problem (out of memory) occur in bodyWriter.CreateFormFile. Could you give me a sample?

Comment: The idea is to get rid of bodyBuf entirely; and write to the http stream object instead. I can't give a better example without a better idea of exactly what you're trying to achieve

Comment: [Here is what I want](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272663/transfer-a-big-file-in-golang/23278957?noredirect=1#23278957)